# Deploying deepstream.io behind nginx

Tags: javascript, nginx, deployment, deepstream.io

We have kerberos authentication at our nginx layer and want to connect to deepstream.io instances as a reverse proxy.  From my reading of the docs, it looks like putting a webserver in front of deepstream.io instances will hamper performance.  Also, there is the question of who does load balancing - usually it is at nginx layer but deepstream.io does seem to have inbuilt capabilities to ask other instances to handle load (via [messaging](https://deepstream.io/tutorials/writing-messaging-connector.html))

What would be the best way to get deepstream.io instances play well with a web server ? It is non-trivial to re-implement kerberos authentication in Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible (and a good idea) to deploy and loadbalance deepstream behind Nginx, HAProxy etc. There are a few things to be aware of though:

**engine.io, websockets and sticky sessions**.

Deepstream uses [engine.io](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io) (the transport-layer behind [socket.io](http://socket.io/)) to connect to browsers.

engine.io uses a number of different transport mechanisms, most notably long-polling (keeping an http request open until data needs to be send) and WebSockets.

For long-polling it is crucial that all requests from the same client are routed to the same deepstream server, so make sure that sticky/persistent sessions are enabled in your nginx upstream group (just add the [ip_hash directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#ip_hash)). For websocket it is important that [the http update headers are forwarded](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/).

**sync data / messages between your deepstream nodes**

Make sure that your deepstream nodes are connected with each other, both by a cache and message-bus. You have a choice of caches and messaging systems, but the simplest is to just use [Redis](http://redis.io/) for both. Have a look at the section on *"What’s the simplest production-ready setup?"* at the bottom of https://deepstream.io/tutorials/connectors-and-deployment.html.

**TCP Connections from other clients (e.g. NodeJS)**
engine.io is mainly used for browser clients, backend processes may directly connect via TCP. Loadbalancing TCP connections is perfectly possible with NginX, but requires an [extra stream group in your configuration.](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/tcp-load-balancing/)